# Amazon Glacier KeyNotFoundException

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-glacier

I keep getting the following exception when trying to upload a file to Amazon Glacier using the .NET sdk:

```
System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
   at Amazon.Glacier.Model.Internal.MarshallTransformations.UploadArchiveResponseUnmarshaller.UnmarshallException(JsonUnmarshallerContext context, Exception innerException, HttpStatusCode statusCode)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Transform.JsonResponseUnmarshaller.UnmarshallException(UnmarshallerContext input, Exception innerException, HttpStatusCode statusCode)
   at Amazon.Runtime.AmazonWebServiceClient.handleHttpWebErrorResponse(AsyncResult asyncResult, WebException we)
   at Amazon.Runtime.AmazonWebServiceClient.getResponseCallback(IAsyncResult result)
   at Amazon.Runtime.AmazonWebServiceClient.endOperation[T](IAsyncResult result)
   at Amazon.Glacier.Transfer.Internal.SinglepartUploadCommand.Execute()
   at Amazon.Glacier.Transfer.ArchiveTransferManager.Upload(String vaultName, String archiveDescription, String filepath, UploadOptions options)
   at UClaim.TaskRunner.Tasks.ArchiveDocuments.Execute() in c:\Projects\uclaim\src\UClaim.TaskRunner\Tasks\ArchiveDocuments.cs:line 55
```

I've got no idea why it's happening or what it means, and googling is turning up nothing. The code I'm using is nothing special, but here it is for completeness.

```
var document = GetDocumentToArchive();
var manager = new ArchiveTransferManager(Amazon.RegionEndpoint.EUWest1);
document.ArchiveId = manager.Upload(
    "archivedDocs",
    string.Format("#{0}: {1}", document.Claim.Id, document.Description),
    document.GeneratePathOnServer()).ArchiveId;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok turns out this was a stupid mistake. I thought that the SDK would create the vault if it didn't exist but I guess it was attempting to look it up and failing. I logged in to the management console and created the "archivedDocs" vault and now it runs fine